# String comparisons in JasperReports expressions

Tags: jasper-reports

A database field named `income_source` is queried using:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE income_source LIKE "salaried%"
```

This retrieves `income_source` values with a "salaried" prefix. In iReport, the **PrintWhenExpression** value for the field is set as:

```
$F{income_source}.equals("Salaried")? Boolean.TRUE:Boolean.FALSE
```

Why does the report output differ from the SQL output?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few problems:

- The value `"salaried%"` in the SQL differs from the value of `"Salaried"` in the expression.
- The value `"salaried%"` uses the `%` to match all text after the letter `d`.
- There is a bit of redundancy in the **PrintWhenExpression**.

Try the following expression:

```
$F{income_source}.startsWith( "salaried" )
```

Or:

```
$F{income_source}.trim().toLowerCase().startsWith( "salaried" )
```

One of those should work. You will also want to ensure **Blank when null** is checked. Otherwise, the expression becomes:

```
$F{income_source} == null ? Boolean.FALSE :
  $F{income_source}.trim().toLowerCase().startsWith( "salaried" )
```